# HTML form with custom function call

Tags: javascript, html, forms, winjs

I am developing Universal windows 8.1 app and I have a page for creating new contact.
In purpose to validate input fields I put them in form. My form action not supposed to go to service it just need to validate fields and call custom function.

HTML:

```
<form name="myform" onSubmit="JavaScript:OnSubmitForm()">
     <div>
         <label>
             First name<br />
             <input id="contactFirstName" class="win-textbox" type="text" name="firstName" required />
         </label>
     </div>
     <div>
         <label>
             Last name<br />
             <input id="contactLastName" class="win-textbox" type="text" name="lastName" />
         </label>
     </div>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
     <input type="button" value="Cancel"/>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    function OnSubmitForm()
    {
        alert('click');
    }
});
```

My alert is never calls in plain HTML project neither in WinJS app. I also tried with:

```
  <form name="myform" onsubmit="return OnSubmitForm();">
```

and the same.

Does it a good approach at all, to use form just for input fields validation or there is better way, and why this does not work ?

Comment: Do you see error log in Browser's console of undefined function or something ?

Comment: I see that error "uncaught reference" logged in console on button click, but error just blink i cannot catch it. Also input filed are empty after submit like everything is ok.

Comment: return false in the function OnSubmitForm() so that your page doesn't redirect and you can see the error.

Comment: Even with "return false" I could not catch the error, error just blinked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inline `event-binding` expects functions to be under `global-scope` and that is one of the reason one should not use it!

In your example, `OnSubmitForm` is under the local scope of `DOMContentLoaded` handler. Best approach would be to use `addEventListener` and with the current code, place `OnSubmitForm` out of `DOMContentLoaded`.

```js
document.getElementById('myform').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); //to prevent form submission
  alert('click');
});
```

```html
<form name="myform" id='myform'>
  <div>
    <label>
      First name
      <br />
      <input id="contactFirstName" class="win-textbox" type="text" name="firstName" required />
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>
      Last name
      <br />
      <input id="contactLastName" class="win-textbox" type="text" name="lastName" />
    </label>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  <input type="button" value="Cancel" />
</form>
```

**With current approach:**

```js
function OnSubmitForm() {
  alert('click');
}
```

```html
<form name="myform" onSubmit="JavaScript:OnSubmitForm()">
  <div>
    <label>
      First name
      <br />
      <input id="contactFirstName" class="win-textbox" type="text" name="firstName" required />
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>
      Last name
      <br />
      <input id="contactLastName" class="win-textbox" type="text" name="lastName" />
    </label>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  <input type="button" value="Cancel" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it solve all my problems. e.preventDefault(); also was important thing here.

Comment: @Milos, Yeah! You must have it conditional if you want to submit a `form` is all validations are tested fine!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [parsley.js](http://parsleyjs.org)?

I created this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qkkdf78k/) to show you a quick example.

```
<form name="myform">
 <div>
     <label>
         First name<br />
         <input id="contactFirstName" data-parsley-required-message="First name required" class="win-textbox" type="text" name="firstName" required data-parsley-trigger="change focusout" data-parsley-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z]*$/"/>
     </label>
 </div>
 <div>
     <label>
         Last name<br />
         <input id="contactLastName" class="win-textbox" type="text" name="lastName" />
     </label>
 </div>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
 <input type="button" value="Cancel"/>
```

```
<script src="http://parsleyjs.org/dist/parsley.js"></script>
<script>
    window.ParsleyConfig = {
        errorsWrapper: '<div></div>',
        errorTemplate: '<div class="alert alert-danger parsley" role="alert"></div>',
        errorClass: 'has-error',
        successClass: 'has-success'
    };
</script>
```

Comment: I have never tried this library. This is answer on my first question is there any better/other way for input field validation ?