# Javascript function getting cutoff?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using MVC to build a login page. I have a Javascript function that gets called when the submit button is clicked. However I noticed in the debugger that the function doesnt get executed fully. Here is my code:

```
@{
    string loginError = (string)ViewData["loginError"];
}


<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkLogin() {
        if (@loginError != null)
        {
            var message = '@loginError';
            if (message)
            alert(message);
        }
    }
</script>


<form class="login-form" action="/Login/Login" method="POST">

    <div class="login-form__content">

        <div class="login-form__header">Login to your account</div>

        <input class="login-form__input" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">

        <input class="login-form__input" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">

        <button class="login-form__button" type="submit" onsubmit="checkLogin();">Login</button>

        <p></p>

        <button class="login-form__button" type="submit" formaction="/Register/Create" id="signupbutton">Sign up</button>

    </div>

</form>
```

So, assuming that a user enters the wrong credentials, the loginError variable will be assign a value "Invalid username or password". Oddly after the line: var message = '@loginError', the function just stops there.

Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Is there a way to submit the form and call the function at the same time? Or to achieve the purpose of the function and to also submit the form?

Comment: The former did not work, unfortunately. For the latter, do you mean: onclick="checkLogin(); return false;"? Should my function be updated with return false? (But I'm not sure where to put it if that's the case)

Comment: Never mind what I said. Looking at your code again it seems the issue is in the order it is executed. First the form is loaded without an error. Then when clicking on the submit button, will the `checkLogin()` function be executed (error still being `null`). Then the page is submitted and reloaded this time presumably with the error not being `null`. But it wont be alerted until you hit the submit button again, submitting the form for the second time. You're probably better off getting rid of the alert altogether (it is deprecated anyway) and place the error somewhere in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function checkLogin() {
    if (@loginError != null)
    {
        var message = '@loginError';
        if (message)
            alert(message);
    }
}
```

What I think happened was that the program stopped because you forgot to indent the alert, and the program ran alert(message) every time, even without the if statement.

This was the first problem I saw, so this maybe isn't the problem.

Comment: Sorry, it didnt work... Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: Javascript doesn't care about indentation. Whether or not you indent your code doesn't change anything in Javascript (other than readability).

Answer (score 0):

checklogin reloads onsubmit and breaks in the middle of the execution of javascript. make sure you put return false; onsubmit in order to execute javascript and to disable reload.

you can see example here:
[HTML form with custom function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36769465/html-form-with-custom-function-call)

Comment: How would you code it? Sorry I'm very new to Javascript

Answer (score 0):

checklogin reloads onsubmit and breaks in the middle of the execution of javascript. make sure you put return false; onsubmit in order to execute javascript and to disable reload.

you can see example here
[HTML form with custom function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36769465/html-form-with-custom-function-call)